# How to return multiple values from a Javascript function

Tags: jquery

I have got the below JSON format array

```
[
    {
        "id": "0004",
        "name": "Thums Up",
        "image": {
            "url": "pepsicup.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 200
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "category_name": "can",
                "image": "images/0001.jpg",
                "type": [
                    {
                        "type": "250ml",
                        "price": "50"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "300ml",
                        "price": "150"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "330ml",
                        "price": "200"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "category_name": "bottle",
                "image": "images/0001.jpg",
                "type": [
                    {
                        "type": "350ml",
                        "price": "60"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "600ml",
                        "price": "110"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "category_name": "fountain",
                "image": "images/0001.jpg",
                "type": [
                    {
                        "type": "small",
                        "price": "160"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "large",
                        "price": "260"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

Right now i am parsing that using the below function and returning the type 250ml , 300ml and 330ml .

Is it possible to return multiple values ??

I mean i want to return type , price and the image also ??

if it is not possible to include the image in the return type , with the above , i can change json structure so that  the type can have image also with in it .

```
function returndeepervaluesforinner(value) {
    var innerdata  = [];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(retdata));
    for(var i = 0; i < retdata.length; i++) {
        if (retdata[i].name == "Thums Up") {
            for (var b = 0; b < retdata[i].category.length; b++) {
                if (retdata[i].category[b].category_name == "can") {
                    for (var d = 0; d < retdata[i].category[b].type.length; d++) {
                        innerdata.push(retdata[i].category[b].type[d].type);
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    }
    return innerdata;
}
```

Comment: Short answer, return an array containing those values.

Comment: an object would be even better..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , how to combine those arrays in the return type and retrive them??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that I'd prefer. You can return an array of objects so that you can return multiple values.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/SALU9/1/)**

```
$.each(arr, function(i, item) {
    $.each(item.category, function(j, item){
        obj.image=item.image;
        obj.type=[];
        obj.price=[];
        $.each(item.type, function(k,e){
            obj.type.push(e.type);
            obj.price.push(e.price)
        });
        objArray.push(obj);
    });
});
return objArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be more than one return from a function. But to send more that one value from a function either store the data to be returned in an array and return the array else store the values in an object of a custom class which has the values to be returned as attributes of the object.

Better way should be to create a class and use it.

Let me know if this was helpful